# Where to Start? SharePoint Dashboards/Live Reporting

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, dashboard-designer-2013, dashboard

I am a fairly new SharePoint Designer and I am swimming through projects for my company from the project level to the corporate level. We have recently been utilizing SharePoint online and I have created dozens of sites for the projects and the corporate office, and have integrated almost everything the company wants, but now I want to capture relevant information and project it in a streamlined "Dashboard" on the home site of any page.

I am currently researching pivot tables to find out whether they would be useful for embedding, but I feel like I'm chasing down this idea down many rabbit holes that wont really lead me to my end goal.

For starters I am wanting to create a dashboard for a help desk that gives me live updates on: How many tickets are open, how many tickets are closed, what type of problems are assigned to which technicians.

Any ideas on where I should start my research to create something like this?

Comment: Where is the data that you would like to report on located? I think best choice would be to use a Data View Web part and customize it to look the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you have data in SharePoint lists you can write custom web applications (content editor) that use REST to query the data from the lists.

If you haven't used REST before you might check out the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569.aspx)

Once you have your data you can then use javascript libraries to make impressive custom graphs (e.g. highchart).

Answer (score 1):

I used [this](http://nicolas.kruchten.com/pivottable/examples/) library to produce pivot tables on few occasions. It is handy but not very impressive looking I must admit.

Taking into account that you are on Office 365, I highly recommend you to look into Power BI for dashboard requirements. Event the free version is capable of doing way more than what you can do within SharePoint. Such as a pie chart that updates other reporting elements every time you click one of the slices. These reports then can be published (embedded) in SharePoint giving a joined up experience.

Answer (score 1):

I use JQuery and [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) to aggregate data from different sites and/or site collections. Then use whatever javascript graphing plug-ins you like. Google's are nice and easy to use (but a lot of companies are anti-Google).

Comment: I think I am a few steps farther behind than I originally thought. I have zero developing experience, and my pages are pretty static. I am not sure how to pull data from lists and libraries into a single web part, let alone bringing it together into an aesthetically pleasing display. I personally love Google, and my company is definitely not anti-google, but would need more knowledge and instruction to do what I think you're suggesting. Thank you! I think this is the answer I am looking for!

Comment: Without developing experience, I'm not sure you can pull the JQuery off. If you can buy third-party software, Bamboo sells a list-rollup web part that will do what you want. You could aggregate data without any third-party software or development using a content query web part, but it will display with only the titles. There are ways to add additional fields, but they require custom xsl. However, there are examples of this online. Look through these results to see if you could handle it: https://www.google.com/search?q=sharepoint+content+roll+up+custom+xsl&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8